# Shell script to replace all occurrnces of string with a value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm new to shell script.
I have a YAML file that consists of placeholder . I need to replace all the occurrences of placeholder `<test-name>` with a value sweta

script.sh

```
Name="sweta"
```

Below is the example of YAML file

```
metadata:
  name: <test-name>-svc
  namespace: abc
spec:
  selector:
    app: <test-name>
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

My expected output is:

```
metadata:
  name: sweta-svc
  namespace: abc
spec:
  selector:
    app: sweta
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

Can someone help me?

Appreciate all your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add your `expected output`?

Comment: Try `sed -i .bak 's/<test-name>/sweta/' yamlfile`. `yamlfile.bak` will be your original file and `yamlfile` will be the modified file.

Comment: Added the expected output.

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis Thank you for your answer. I'm curious to know what does .bak does?

Comment: As I noted above, using `-i .bak` will backup your original file (in case you did something wrong and need to get back to the original state).

Comment: Let's say sweta is assigned to a variable say @name="sweta". How can I modify your solution to accommodate this change?

Comment: @Nikolaos Could please help me missing part here ```sed -i .bak 's/<test-name>/$Name/' abc.yaml. abc.yaml.bak  ```  here $Name="sweta"

Comment: `sed -i .bak "s/<test-name>/$Name/" abc.yaml`, note the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks so much Nikolaos for answering and your time!

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy ways to accomplish your search and replace `<test-name>` string with `sweta`

**Note:** *Assuming your yaml file name is **config.yaml***

---

### Option-1: Using stream editor command 'sed' as below:

To overwrite the original file

```
sed -i 's/<test-name>/sweta/g' config.yaml
```

To write the output to a different file

```
sed 's/<test-name>/sweta/g' config.yaml > updated_config.yaml
```

The syntax of sed command is `sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt`

where
`sed` is the command name

`-i` stands for in-place edit. This option is used to overwrite the original file. If you don't use this, you have to redirect output to a different file as done in second command above.

`s` stands for substitute

`original` is the search string

`new` is the replace string

`g` is for global (replace all occurrences). Omitting this will just replace only the first occurence

`file.txt` is the text file (Linux doesn't use extensions like .txt but people often name files with such extensions as a convention to denote file type)

---

### Option-2: Use 'awk' command:

awk is a very powerful text processing command with its own language syntax, but this search and replace is quite easy:

```
awk '{gsub("<test-name>", "sweta"); print $0}' config.yaml > updated_config.yaml
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the `sed` approach, but -1 for adding the `awk` approach. This is clearly a simple `sed` job, it is pointless to add the `awk` version of it. We could add tens of variations with our favourite scripting language, but the `sed` answer would remain the only sensible one for this trivial task.